# How to Update swagger(Open API spec) through rest API in Azure API Management? Is there any Rest API support re-import using rest api?

Tags: azure, swagger, azure-api-management, openapi

I have created a APIs through importing open api spec(swagger).If I have added a new api into the list I want azure apis to get updated with new list basically re-importing the swagger. Is there any way we can automate it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best is to send JSON body with "fcontentFormat" and "value" set accordingly. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/current-ga/apis/create-or-update?tabs=HTTP#request-body. For example:

```
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "properties": {
    "format": "openapi-link",
    "value": "https://contoso.com/my-api.yaml"
  }
}
```

or

```
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "properties": {
    "format": "openapi+json",
    "value": {
       #OpenAPI document goes here
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The links does not work anymore. new link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2019-01-01/apischema/createorupdate

Comment: ^ and that doesn't work. new link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2019-12-01/apis/createorupdate

Comment: none of these links work now